# Who or what created the time machine in Terminator

Tags: the-terminator, the-terminator-series

I was looking around whether the time machine (or time displacement equipment as it is called in some sources) was actually built by humans or by skynet and somehow couldn't find an answer.

Hence I'll put up the question here - Is this question ever resolved in the Terminator universe?

Comment: [I didn't build the f... thing!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fFkNvdAZ5Vs)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [original script for The Terminator](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Terminator.html) makes it abundantly clear that Skynet developed and built the "Time displacement" technology on its own, using the Terminators as its workforce:

> **REESE:** *...it had no choice. The defensive grid was smashed. We'd taken
>   the mainframes... We'd won.  Taking out Connor then would make no
>   difference.  **Skynet had to wipe out his entire existence.  We captured
>   the lab complex.  Found the...whatever it was called...the
>   time-displacement equipment.** The Terminator had already gone through. 
>   They sent two of us to intercept, then zeroed the whole place. Sumner
>   didn't make it.*

This is then backed up by the official novelisation for [Terminator 2: Judgement Day](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Terminator_2:_Judgment_Day_(Frakes_novel)), in which we (the omniscient reader) learn of the reasoning behind Skynet's research into time technology, for use as a weapon:

> *Until one day the tide of battle turned, and **Skynet, in a desperate
>   burst of brilliance, devised time displacement, the first tactical
>   time weapon.** It sent a lethal emissary back through time to find and
>   eliminate Sarah, so that John Connor might never be born.*

---

It may also interest you to know that according to the official novelisation for [Terminator: Rise of the Machines](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Terminator_3:_Rise_of_the_Machines_(novel)), the fundamental *theoretical basis* for the TDE was done by Einstein and Hawking in the 50s and 1980s (prior to Skynet becoming active):

> *The super black project, funded by the Department of Defense, Central
>   Intelligence Agency, National Reconnaissance Office, and National
>   Security Agency, was designed to create an artificial wormhole.
>   Einstein had first suggested such a phenomenon, and the English
>   theoretical physicist Stephen Hawking had done some work on the
>   possibility. But the problem was power. By most calculations the
>   wattage needed to create an infinitesimally tiny wormhole, in other
>   words a passageway through space-time, would take almost all the
>   energy ever produced in the universe since the moment of the big bang.*

Clearly Skynet used its gigantic brain to overcome this limitation.

Comment: Were there any Force-sensitive Terminators?

Comment: @DVK - [Almost certainly](http://killthehydra.com/wp-content/uploads/terminator-jar-jar-star-wars.jpg)

Comment: *"almost all the energy ever produced in the universe since the moment of the big bang"* – though the amount of energy produced in the universe after Big Bang is zero...

Comment: @Moyli - Pfft. Your "*facts*" have no place here. We prefer uninformed opinion and bad writing.

Comment: @Moyli "almost all the energy" So slightly less than zero, That is why it was a hard problem to solve.

Comment: They just siphon the energy from other universes that don't want to exist quite as much.